# BlockUI on DOM Ready

Tags: jquery, document-ready, blockui

I'm using the jQuery [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) to add a loading splash to a page that takes a few seconds to load due to CAML queries. The problem is, the page loads *before* then the BlockUI displays for a split second and disappears. It seems like JS is executing these in the wrong order and I cannot figure out why. Is there something I can change in the code or is BlockUI just not intended to be used without Ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI();
});
$(window).ready(function() {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

In the html header I call jquery, blockui, and the common.js script that contain the CAML queries and load the page elements (in that order). The common.js script is also run on DOM ready, which I suspect may be part of the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="blockui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.blockUI();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        …
    </body>
</html>
```

This should block the UI way before anything else has been loaded.

**Edit:** Okay, I've bothered to actually look it up … `$.blockUI` supports a callback function.

So, you could/should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        onBlock: function() { 
            // Invoke your CAML stuff here.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well I didn't need the snippy remark-it's not like I didn't bother to read the documentation myself-but what you suggest works great. Thanks.

Comment: @kramden88 I didn't mean to sound snippy at all ;) Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I'm struggling with that for days now! Thanks! Lazy to read as you :)

Comment: @vzwick It is not working correctly in IE8. Blocking the page but th Div message is not shown at all until the scripts finishes loading. Any work around for IE8 ?